# Why with the addition of a gy6 50to100ccbbk,44 stroker,20mm cvk carb with 33 pilot and 105 main jets does my gy6 engine still nog down?

Tags: fuel-system, carburetor, scooter

Gy6 50 to 100cc Tao Tao atm-a1 50 scooter.  I've tried:

- Going up and down on jet sizes
- Cleaning carb
- Replaced carb
- New pod filter
- Advance timing 2 degrees
- New cdl
- Checked fuel flow from carb
- Changed fuel filter
- Added carb cleaner to gas
- Added isopropyl to gas
- New coil
- Tached the air fuel
- Double gasket on cylinder because of 44 stroker
- Set float
- Raised and lowered clip on pilot needle
- Hooked and unhooked the choke
- Checked timing
- Set valve clearance
- Torqued head
- Changed intake manifold

and I'm at a complete loss. It's still bogging down and backfiring.  Please help me.

Comment: Have you checked the quality of the fuel? any water contamination?

Comment: Looks like you've tried EVERYTHING concerning fuel ... how much have you looked at the ignition system? You tried advancing it 2°, did you try retarding it 2° (or more)? Also, have you read the spark plug? What is it telling you?